# Delete rows with repeat column values

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5 VAR6 VAR7 VAR8 VAR9 VAR10 
1   2   1    3    5    2    1    3    5    3    1 
2   1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1 
3   1   3    4    7    2    4    1    3    4    6 
4   2   2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2 
5   1   3    5    6    7    4    6    7    4    6 
6   3   3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
```

How do I delete rows (in this case `ID # 2,4,6`) which have non-distinct values, i.e. the same number in every column, (`1,1,1,1,1`)?

Comment: which database management system are you using?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE 
           VAR1=VAR2 
       AND VAR2=VAR3 
       AND VAR3=VAR4
       AND VAR4=VAR5
       AND VAR5=VAR6
       AND VAR6=VAR7
       AND VAR7=VAR8
       AND VAR8=VAR9
       AND VAR9=VAR10
```

Hopefully you'll need to run this only once - I imagine most of the vars will not be indexed so you'll might end up locking the table or this delete. It would be better to prevent these rows from being inserted I guess.

Comment: Is there a way to do with this with an arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: Please provide more details like the dbms you're using and so on

Comment: You should put that comment on the question, I didn't ask the question and the person asking won't see this comment

Comment: But the question *was* for you: To do this on arbitrary number of columns might be possible in some DBMS but not in others. So which one is your target?

Comment: I was more just wondering in theory if there was a generic way. If I ever came across this situation, I might just do it in PHP and loop through the row and if all values are equal then delete that row

Answer (score 0):

in SQL Server; using `cross apply(values ...)` to unpivot the columns along then aggregate and filter with `count(distinct ...)=1`:

```
delete t
where id in (
  select t.id 
  from t
  cross apply (values (VAR1),(VAR2),(VAR3),(VAR4),(VAR5),(VAR6),(VAR7),(VAR8),(VAR9),(VAR10)
    ) u(Var)
  group by t.id
  having count(distinct u.var)=1
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WZE91559

returns:

```
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| ID | VAR1 | VAR2 | VAR3 | VAR4 | VAR5 | VAR6 | VAR7 | VAR8 | VAR9 | VAR10 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
|  1 |    2 |    1 |    3 |    5 |    2 |    1 |    3 |    5 |    3 |     1 |
|  3 |    1 |    3 |    4 |    7 |    2 |    4 |    1 |    3 |    4 |     6 |
|  5 |    1 |    3 |    5 |    6 |    7 |    4 |    6 |    7 |    4 |     6 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: As I asked the other person that answered, is this possible with an arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: @ZacharyWeixelbaum You'd have to ask a clearer question. What are your criteria for possible, and what exactly do you mean by arbitrary number of columns? Usually columns are not arbitrary, numbers of rows however I can understand being arbitrary. For this answer to apply to a different set of columns, you would change the list of columns in the `values` table constructor. -- In SQL Server you could choose to write this in a more dynamic way with a set method of determining the columns to use and build a query and execute it (dynamic sql).